# Expected 11 bytes, field contained 26 bytes

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I'm trying to import data from a csv file into Teradata using tdload utility with the following command:

```
tdload -h TDPID -u dbc -p dbc -t DemoTable -f demofile.csv -d ',' 
--TargetWorkingDatabase AdventureWorksDW --TargetErrorLimit 100 jobid
```

I get the error :

```
Field length overflow(s) in record 1, field 1, '"ID"'. Expected 11 bytes, 
field contained 26 bytes.
```

How do I fix this?

**Note** - ID is an INTEGER column

Comment: 11 bytes/chars is the maximum length of an integer in characters. Seems your delimiter is not a comma.

Comment: Or the data isn't actually integer.